# "libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install the transcription software Express Scribe. I have installed it just fine on my HP Chromebook 14, but now I'm trying to do it on my desktop. Here is what I started with:

```
sudo su
tar -xvzf scribe.tar.gz
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Everything works fine up until this point; in fact, on my HP Chromebook 14, all I have to enter is the following:

```
./scribe
```

And it automatically installs.

However, on my desktop running Ubuntu 14.04, it's apparently not as simple. After I enter that last command I get the following:

```
Please wait while installer is initialising.....
Release Date: Fri Jan 30 00:51:58 IST 2009
Express Scribe 4.31
/tmp/selfextract.FKS8f2/bin/scribe: error while loading shared libraries: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Installation cancelled
```

So I have tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

And I get the following message:

```
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

So I guess I'm stuck? Not quite sure what to do from here...

Answer (score 26):

Hope you were able to find the solution! Looks like they have pulled ia32-libs from the 14.04 repo. You can install any package with 32-bit compatibility using `program:i386`

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libasound2` worked for me

Comment: This worked for The Dark Mod, but I also needed the plugins as well i.e. `sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386`

Comment: `libasound2` is correct.

Answer (score 13):

On Ubuntu 18.04, We can install using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt search libasound
v   libasound-dev                   -                                           
v   libasound-dev:i386              -                                           
i   libasound2                      - shared library for ALSA applications      
p   libasound2:i386                 - shared library for ALSA applications      
i   libasound2-data                 - Configuration files and profiles for ALSA 
v   libasound2-data:i386            -                                           
p   libasound2-dev                  - shared library for ALSA applications -- de
p   libasound2-dev:i386             - shared library for ALSA applications -- de
p   libasound2-doc                  - documentation for user-space ALSA applicat
p   libasound2-plugin-equal         - equalizer plugin for ALSA                 
p   libasound2-plugin-equal:i386    - equalizer plugin for ALSA                 
p   libasound2-plugin-smixer        - smixer plugin for ALSA library            
p   libasound2-plugin-smixer:i386   - smixer plugin for ALSA library            
i   libasound2-plugins              - ALSA library additional plugins           
p   libasound2-plugins:i386         - ALSA library additional plugins           
p   libasound2-plugins-extra        - ALSA library additional plugins           
p   libasound2-plugins-extra:i386   - ALSA library additional plugins           
v   libasound2-plugins:i386         -                                           
v   libasound2:i386                 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Some programs want exactly `libportaudio.so` but my system has `libportaudio.so.2` so the answer is obvious ... simlink:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so
```